# Can I free() static and automatic variables in C?

Tags: c, free, scope, static-variables, dynamic-allocation

The code is as follow :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int num = 3;   // Static external variable
int *ptr = &num;

int main(void)
{
 int num2 = 4;  // Automatic variable
 int *ptr2 = &num2;

 free(ptr);  //Free static variable
 free(ptr2); //Free automatic variable

 return 0; 
}
```

I try to compile the above code and it works, I'm curious does the `free()` function able to free both the static variable and also automatic variable? Or basically it does nothing?

Comment: It "works" for sufficiently low quality definition of "works". It may also crash, even on the same system, the same compiler, or different compile options. It's simply **undefined behaviour** -- anything can happen, even something expected.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Calling `free()` on a pointer not returned by memory allocating functions(`malloc`,`calloc` etc) causes **Undefined Behavior**.
Your code has an Undefined Behavior, So the compiler does not need to give you any diagnostic of it and it can show any behavior, it might work, or crash, or literally do anything.

Just avoid writing code which causes an Undefined Behavior is the only solution.

Comment: You can also call free() on a NULL pointer, as that is defined behavior.  Just make sure that you never call free() twice on the *same* pointer.

Comment: @caramel23: All You can get guarantee of is an Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do that. `free` is only used for memory dynamically allocated from heap by `malloc` family of functions.

Memory for `num` is statically allocated in data segment and can't be released. Memory for `num2` is allocated in the `main`'s call stack frame and will be released as soon as `main` returns.

What actually happens depend on implementation of `free`. There are usually specific data structures maintained in heap to help `malloc`/`free` track the allocated and free memory areas. `free` expects these data structures to be somewhere around the place its argument points to. An when you pass it a pointer which doesn't point to a `malloc`-allocated heap area, it'll consider garbage data as some useful information and do some strange things. And you're lucky if the result is just an immediate program crash.